# error in creating data tables in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a dashboard using shiny app. The data to the dashboard is coming from the database .
Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(RODBC)

ui <- fluidPage( titlePanel(title=(div(tags$a("Annual  Report"))), windowTitle = "Annual  Report"),
               sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                                                    
                    selectInput("GEOGRAPHY","SELECT GEOGRAPHY",choices = 'GEOGRAPHY')
                                ) ,
   
   mainPanel(tableOutput("tbl") 
   ) 
               )
) 
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    output$tbl <- renderTable({
                conn1 <- odbcConnect("database name", pwd = "pwd")
           
        tbl1 <-  sqlQuery(conn1, paste("select * from tablename"))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is my output:   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWvQj.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWvQj.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPAct.png)
side bar and main panel is displaying but when i click on the drop down the data isn't pulling from table. select GEOGRAPHY means it has to give the all the options in GEOGRAPHY.
In the choice if i mention choices = tbl$'GEOGRAPHY' it sys object not found.I dont want to manually enter the choices as there are several values. from the drop down i have to select .

[side bar and main panel is displaying reactive data isn't displaying .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWvQj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `updateSelectInput` to change the `choices` after your data from `tbl1` is available.

I also added `odbcClose` after the query, and `subset` so the table displayed will show results based on the selected `GEOGRAPHY` choice.

**Edit**: You can add an option "All" to your `selectInput`. If "All" is selected, then all data will be displayed. Otherwise, it will filter on the selection.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tbl1 <- reactive({
    conn1 <- odbcConnect("database name", pwd = "pwd")
    data <- sqlQuery(conn1, paste("select * from tablename"))
    odbcClose(conn1)
    data
  })
  
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    if (input$GEOGRAPHY != "All") {
      subset(tbl1(), GEOGRAPHY == input$GEOGRAPHY)
    } else {
      tbl1()
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "GEOGRAPHY", choices = c("All", tbl1()$GEOGRAPHY))
  })
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked in one way. But i wanted my entire dataset to be displayed first and then filter it .

Comment: I couldn't get the output as desired.. tried in different ways. In the drop down instead of names it is displaying page numbers.

Comment: I got the output if i am using other column which is a number.If i filter by GEO_HD it is working. The variable which i am trying to filter is character data type. May be in the selectinput i have assign the dat type. Thanks for all your help